# Is there any restriction in calling _trackPageview per minute?

Tags: google-analytics

I use this code to send my feedback to GA but when I run it, at first it works correctly but after a while for example 400 _trackPageview call I can't see my result in REAL_TIME(BETA) part of GA And when I clear my cookies it works correctly again.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-27966345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
function guidGenerator() {
var S4 = function() {
   return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
};
return (S4()+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+S4()+S4());
}
function get_url(){
    var a=document.URL;
    var s=a.lastIndexOf('caillou/');
    return a.substring(s);
}
function sent_report(action,label,Cvalue){
         var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
     var value = pageTracker._getVisitorCustomVar(3);
     if(!value){
    value=guidGenerator();
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3,'User_ID',value,1]);
     }
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',value,action,label,Cvalue]);
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit to how many requests (events AND page views) per visitor session GA will track.  Refer to the [event tracking guide](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#implementationConsiderations) for details. It "works" again when you clear cookies because clearing cookies deletes your visitor info and GA counts it as a new visit/session.